# How do you declare function params in typescript with an interface?

Tags: javascript, typescript, types

I know in TS I can do:

`const myFunc = (choice: string, index: number) => {}`

but how would I use an interface in there (and should I in terms of best practice?)

I want to do something like

```
interface myFuncArgs {
  choice: string
  index: number
}
const myFunc = (choice, index): myFuncArgs  => {}
```

but it doesn't like that

I know for this simple case it doesn't really make sense but what if `choice` was a complex object and I wanted to declare the types of everything inside? it would look ugly inline.

how do I do this?

Comment: Considering you pass an object as a function parameter, you may do `const myFunc = ({choice, index}: myFuncArgs): void => {}` (assuming `void` is a type of return)

Comment: ah look  good. you can answer this and I will accep

Comment: Thank you. If that works for you, just feel free to delete the question.

Comment: might be useful in the future to someone?

Answer (score 0):

You can do what @YevgenGorbunkov said in comments:

```
const myFunc = ({choice, index}: myFuncArgs): void => {}
```

Or you can even do (if you don't like to pass an object):

```
type MyFunc = (choice : myFuncArgs['choice'], index: myFuncArgs['index']) => void

const myFunc : MyFunc = (choice, index) => {

}
```

[Playground.](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgLYE8BiBXECCCUA5gM7IDeAUMsggBYD2wSAXMiWFKEdcqACYQAHmxDZUAI2iUAvpUph0ABxQBZLLgTIAvMgAU9JkmRsMOPIVIBtAOSHmEGwF0ANHxCCRaDReIlbAsLOAJQ6AHzIAG5M-PIIDCAc3uZabOopOvr2SG6BQqHaEVQ0NPGJDAA2EAB0FQxEBowOwQDcvKUJJJU1dQ15rbKUQA)